# Loop array issue

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to write a simple array, I have written many arrays but I don't understand why on this occasion I am not getting the desired result.

Below is the code I am using, so I am generating a report name and putting them in an array to retrieve later on by referencing the index number,

So the debug within the loop works and I can see theem being stored, when I am outside the loop cannot retrieve it so cannot recall.

Any ideas?

```
  For i = 1 To num
        reportname = API & SetPeriod & APIEnd
        ReDim retrieve(1 To i)
        retrieve(i) = reportname
        SetPeriod = SetPeriod + 1
        Debug.Print retrieve(i)
    Next i
    ReDim retrieve(1 To 4)
    Debug.Print retrieve(2)
    Debug.Print retrieve(2)
```

Comment: If you showed more code it would be helpful. It also looks like you ReDim'em but alos didnt preserve. that also might account for it

Comment: Why `ReDim retrieve(1 To i)` in the loop? Why not simply `ReDim retrieve(1 To num)` prior to the loop? (`ReDim Preserve` in the loop would probably give you the results that you expect but would be very inefficient since `ReDim Preserve` is an expensive operation).

Comment: that is a very good question @JohnColeman you are correct that will solve the problem as I will always know my array size which is driven by num.

Comment: That “ReDim retrieve(1 To 4)” is clearing the array. So don’t use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to **keep the values** inside your array when you resize it, then you will need to use the `Preserve` option when you `ReDim`.

So your statement would look like:

```
ReDim Preserve retrieve(1 To i)
```

But if it's at all possible, try to declare the size of your array one time as changing its size multiple times can cause performance issues, especially when using `Preserve`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already set and get the value of variable `num` before entering your `For i = 1 to Num` loop, you can use that value to `Redim` your array to the right size, just use `ReDim retrieve(1 To num)`, and you don't need to `Redim` every time you enter the loop`.

***Modified Code***

```
ReDim retrieve(1 To num) ' redim you array to the size of num

For i = 1 To num
    reportname = API & SetPeriod & APIEnd
    retrieve(i) = reportname
    SetPeriod = SetPeriod + 1
    Debug.Print retrieve(i)
Next i
```